# Stargazer for ARDL package's output: 'Error: Unrecognized object type'

Tags: r, stargazer, ardl

So `ARDL` package in R implements `dynlm` which is an accepted input in `stargazer` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59528346/how-do-i-fix-the-unrecognized-object-error-in-stargazer-with-a-dynlm-model) question and answer.

However, I am unable to get stargazer table from `ardl` or `auto_ardl`. It throws the *unrecognized object type* error. Is there a way out of this?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(10)
library(ARDL)
library(stargazer)
x=rnorm(100,mean = 5,sd=2)
y=rnorm(100,mean = 7,sd=3)
df=cbind(x,y)
model1=auto_ardl(y~x,data = df,max_order = 4)

class(model1)
[1] "list"
stargazer(model1)

% Error: Unrecognized object type.

class(model1$best_model)
[1] "dynlm" "lm"    "ardl" 
stargazer(model1$best_model)

% Error: Unrecognized object type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I don't know how to do this in `stargazer`, but this model type is supported out-of-the box by the latest version of the [`modelsummary` package](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary) (disclaimer: I am the maintainer).

```r
set.seed(10)

library(ARDL)
library(modelsummary)

x=rnorm(100,mean = 5,sd=2)
y=rnorm(100,mean = 7,sd=3)
df=cbind(x,y)
model1=auto_ardl(y~x,data = df,max_order = 4)

modelsummary(model1$best_model)
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 6.849 |
|  | (1.705) |
| L(y, 1) | 0.061 |
|  | (0.106) |
| x | -0.103 |
|  | (0.166) |
| L(x, 1) | -0.027 |
|  | (0.167) |
| L(x, 2) | -0.075 |
|  | (0.166) |
| L(x, 3) | 0.043 |
|  | (0.167) |
| L(x, 4) | 0.048 |
|  | (0.169) |
| Num.Obs. | 96 |
| R2 | 0.013 |
| R2 Adj. | -0.054 |
| AIC | 492.8 |
| BIC | 513.3 |
| Log.Lik. | -238.398 |

Comment: thanks for this. I am not my computer right now but will surely try this. Does your package gives latex output? If not then perhaps I can feed this in `kable` to get a latex output but the s.e. may come in a separate row. In anycase, thanks for this alternative option.

Comment: Also, if the estimates are significant then would there be asterisks also? The intercept here appears to be significant but yet there's no asterisk on it.

Comment: The package can do LaTeX, Word, JPG, HTML, Markdown output, and it can be integrated in Rmarkdown documents. If you want LaTeX, just set `output="latex"`. You can add significance stars by setting the argument `stars=TRUE` or use the `stars` argument to set your own custom levels and symbols (it is `FALSE` by default).

Comment: That's great!! This looks perfect then. Accepting answer.